# any best practice how many Realm instance in one single app?

Tags: realm

one app should have limited instance of sqlite, or in other word, one db should be enough for one app at most cases.
But for Realm, is there any best practice or recommended solution? just like sqlite or the app can has as many as they want like file system.

Answer (score 0):

You can have as many (or as few) Realm files in your app as you'd like! Please read Realm's documentation section on using multiple realm files here: http://realm.io/docs/cocoa/#other-realms.